# Will allah forgive a muslim who used to pretend that he's allah?

Tags: quran, allah, shirk

So this question popped up on my mind,since shirk is the greatest sin of all what about the muslim who are pretending tobe allah,will allah forgive the muslim if the muslim did sincere repentance?

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to come up with sins greater than `shirk` you must first learn to type and capitalize the name of Allah properly.

If one is sincere with his repentance, there is absolutely nothing Allah cannot forgive. [Says Allah in the Qur'an:](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=7&verse=156)

> My punishment—I afflict with it whom I will, but **My mercy encompasses
> all things.**

To assume that one has the ability to commit a sin Allah cannot forgive, is perhaps a greater sin than `shirk.` The key point is **sincere** repentance.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all Please stop asking the same question in different posts.**

---

Come on what's wrong with you Brother? Everyone here trying to say that Allah will forgive you. But you are still asking the same question. Or do you think Allah's mercy is not enough? Don't fall into devil's trick.

Firaun did something similar of what you are saying:

> **saying, “I am your lord, the most high!”**

*Quran 79:24*

Firaun claimed that he is god. But Allah said to Musa AS:

> **And speak to him with gentle speech that perhaps he may be reminded or
> fear [Allah]."**

*Quran 20:44*

Allah didn't said leave him alone there is no hope for him, instead Allah told Musa AS to speak to him with gentle speech so that he may realize his mistake .So there was still hope for firaun if he repented and came back to Allah.

Allah said in *Quran 7:156*:

> **..My mercy encompasses all things."**

***If you still think Allah will not forgive you, if you repent. You maybe unknowingly insulting his mercy.***

Answer (score 0):

In the name of Allah, the most gracious, the most merciful.

Shirk maybe a sin that touches the tallest clouds, but Allah forgives such sin also, with sincere repentance.

In Surah Az-Zumar 39:53, it is said

> [image]
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

I will leave you with this: Never underestimate the power and the limits of Allah. There is a reason why we are allowed to seek forgiveness.

Comment: Is it worse than shirk? If it is, will allah forgive the person if he did repentance?

Comment: Allah will even forgive shirk if you repent while you are alive. So no matter what have you done. As long as you are breathing the door of forgiveness is there.

Comment: Allah gives alot of chances during our life to ask forgiveness. If someone says, "I don't have time" then, are you reading quran 24/7? Why not take 5 minutes from your YouTube time and turn towards Allah and ask forgiveness.

Comment: What i mean is,if a muslim used to claim that he is allah will allah forgive him if he did repentance? Im not talking about shirk

Comment: We don't know if Allah will forgive you. No human knows that. All we know is that Allah does forgive its people.