# Will Allah forgive me for misbehaving with parents?

Tags: allah

This incident is around a year ago. Me and my mom had a heated argument. At that moment i got extremely angry and pulled her hair. I am regretful for what i did. But it doesn’t mean she was not at fault.She always screams at us if we do mistakes.  I don’t mind if she beat me or yell at me. The problem is she uses cuss word. She even used it many times in front of other person. I know i committed a big sin. But it was not only my fault. I want to ask forgiveness. How can i do that?

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/63508/37617

Answer (score 0):

> (53) Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." [Az-Zumar].

You have to hasten to sincerely repent to God Almighty, perhaps God Almighty may forgive you and repent of you, because the one who repents from sin is like one who has no sin, and if the son repents to God Almighty from his disobedience and forgives his mother, then repentance erases what came before it, and the repentant of sin is like one who has no sin.

Answer (score 0):

Assalmaualikum,

Remember Allah (SWT) is the All-Merciful (AR-RAHMAN). But, the sin done was wrong too. Allah (SWT) will judge your mother according to her deeds, but even saying a word of ''ufff'' to your parents is a major sin. Try to make your relationship better with her, and love her, so she will love you.